# Check if similar row with same ID is already inserted into table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, insert, prepared-statement

I have a `Car` table with columns `carID, brand, color, price`. I'm copying `carID` and `color` to another table `Detail` which have columns `carID, finish, color` (with `carID` being a foreign key from `Car` table and the `finish` column is not `NULL`).

I have an SQL Prepared Statement:

```
public void insertToDetail(int carID, String finish){

     String sql = "INSERT INTO detail (carID, finish, color) SELECT ?, ?, color FROM car WHERE carID = ?;";

     PreparedStatement psmt = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

     psmt.setString(1, carID);
     psmt.setInt(2, finish);
     psmt.setInt(3, carID);
     psmt.executeUpdate();  
     psmt.close();
}
```

How may I check if an exact same `carID` value is not already inserted into my `Detail` table?

I tried something like:

```
"INSERT INTO detail (carID, finish, color) 
SELECT ?, ?, color FROM car 
WHERE NOT EXISTS {
     SELECT carID 
     FROM detail 
     WHERE carID = ?
 } ;";
```

And it gave me the error:

> MySQLSyntaxError You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '{ SELECT carID FROM detail WHERE carID = 123 }' at
>   line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are trying to write is:

```
INSERT INTO detail (carID, finish, color) 
    SELECT ?, ?, color
    FROM car 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT carID 
                      FROM detail 
                      WHERE carID = ?
                     ) ;
```

However, `NOT EXISTS` is the wrong approach.  Let the database do the checking.  So create a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_detail_carid on detail(carID);
```

This will generate duplicate car ids in the table.  An `insert` will return an error if a duplicate is generated.

To prevent the error, use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO detail (carID, finish, color) 
    SELECT ?, ?, color
    FROM car 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE carID = VALUES(carID);
```

Comment: By creating a `UNIQUE INDEX` is that the same as having a `PRIMARY KEY` function?  So `carID` will become a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @JamesMcTyre . . . No.  A primary key is unique, but a unique key does not have to be the primary key.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql have syntax error,need to change `{}` to `()` and remove `;` at the end

so change

```
"INSERT INTO detail (carID, finish, color) SELECT ?, ?, color FROM car WHERE NOT EXISTS {
SELECT carID FROM detail WHERE carID = ?;";
```

to

```
"INSERT INTO detail (carID, finish, color) SELECT ?, ?, color FROM car WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT carID, finish, color FROM detail WHERE carID = ?)";
```

Comment: I made an edit to my question with my SQL before I saw your post

Comment: @JamesMcTyre `{}` it's invalid syntax in `mysql`

Comment: Ok, now my sql is not throwing a syntax error but it's now inserting the same row twice in a row instead of only one time...

Comment: @JamesMcTyre Now the sql itself have no problem,it works fine in my side,you need to check other parts of your code

Comment: Will something like `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT carID FROM detail WHERE carID = ?) INSERT INTO detail (carID, finish, color) SELECT ?, ? color FROM car WHERE carID = ?`  work?

Comment: @JamesMcTyre No,it won't work,I would advice you to test the sql directly and then test it in your jdbc code